How to add Subdomains and Users custom domains to my vercel project?
Im currently building an application using vercel and next js.
I want to allow my users to have an subdomain so user1.myapp.com and also allow them to have add their domain to my project so user1.com
I also have the problem that my domain has the TLD .de and vercel doesnt support them so i cannot transfer it to vercel. (Im also not sure if i have to do that so i realise my idea)
Does anyone already had this problem and knows how to fix it?
Best regards and thanks
I already read through Vercel Platform Startet Kit but im not sure if its what i need.

You don't need to transfer a domain to Vercel, just point the A/CNAME records to it and it will work.
Your question is not a simple one at all. I would recommend learning the basics about DNS. It is not an easy topic, but it will help a lot down the line.
Other than that, check https://vercel.com/templates/next.js/platforms-starter-kit
